# Async/await parsing json

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

So i have a piece of code like here and need to refactor it to use map/forEach.

```
       async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
          for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
              await callback(array[index], index, array);
          }
       }
```

But when i use map like below it just parses the whole json without waiting for individual entries of the array to send each entry with delay in callback function.

```
      async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
       await array.map(async (item, index) => {
         await callback(array[index], index, array);
       });
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And I am confused that someone wants to destroy a readable, maintainable, fast code solution with something that just looks 'fancy'. But who am I to judge :)

Comment: @larwa1n ... which is way faster though (if parallel execution is intended)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Promise.all` as `await` on an array (although it contains promises) does nothing:

```
 await Promise.all(array.map(/*...*/));
```

I'd write it as:

```
  const asyncForEach = (array, callback) =>
     Promise.all(array.map(callback));
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `await` infront of the callback.

Comment: @kemicofa um, ... nope?

Comment: I don't think this will map 1:1 with the original code.  This will fire all the requests at the same time and wait on them all.  The original `for` will only have 1 going at a time.

Comment: @zero298 yup, I think thats what the user wants (probably).

Comment: This solution still runs through the whole json insted of firing 1 entry and waiting for 3s. any way to make it fire 1 entry of array at a time?

Comment: @dobbey not with `map` nor `forEach`, if you want that stick to a `for` loop.